# remove duplicate parent tag based on child attributes value in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have  below XML file where in I need to remove the ExemptionList tag based on the child tag Exemption attribute value ,if child tag attribute value is same,
need to remove the duplicate parent-child tags.

Input XML:

```
 <MaterialInfo>
        <ExemptionList>
          <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
          <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature" identity="7(a)"/>
        </ExemptionList>
        <ExemptionList>
          <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
          <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature" identity="7(a)"/>
        </ExemptionList>
</MaterialInfo>
```

Expected Output XML :

```
<MaterialInfo>
        <ExemptionList>
          <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
          <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature" identity="7(a)"/>
        </ExemptionList>
</MaterialInfo>
```

Solution required based on XSLT v2.0 transformation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Eliminating duplicates can be done by grouping and only outputting the first item in each group so check the introduction to grouping in your favourite XSLT book or in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info, then give it a try. As for your sample. to you want to identify duplicates solely based on the `identity` attribute of the `Exemption` element?

Comment: Yes for my example , duplicates should be identified solely based on the identity attribute of the Exemption element

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
<xsl:template match="MaterialInfo">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="@identity">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
<xsl:template>
```

This assumes that equal `@identity` is enough to identify two elements as duplicates.

Comment: I have tried the same ,but its not producing expected output 
and just to highlight the identity attribute will also be avaliable for other TAG under MaterialInfo TAG .I want this change to reflect only for ExemptionList Tag

Comment: You only gave a rough outline of the requirement, so I only provided a rough outline of the solution. At this stage it's best to start a new question showing your complete stylesheet, the actual output, and the required output: that way, we can see more easily what you haven't understood about the solution (or what we haven't understood about the requirement).

Comment: I have created new question as suggested by you.Please check the below URL for the new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870964/removing-duplicate-tag-based-on-child-attribute-value-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to group the `ExemptionList` elements by the value of the `identity` attribute of the `Exemption` child element:

```
  <xsl:template match="MaterialInfo">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="ExemptionList" group-by="Exemption/@identity">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3Y has an XSLT 3 example but for an XSLT 2 processor you just would need to replace the `xsl:mode` declaration used there by the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```