# Removing duplicate Tag based on child attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

```
Have couple of element with same Parent and child node.
So need to remove the duplicates.
```

Expected output should be using XSLT.
Thanks in advance
In the input XML ,there are  element with same child node, which i need to remove based on the  tag attribute value.If same attribute value("identity" attribute) in both  tag then the entire duplicate  tag should be removed and displayed only once

```
Input XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MainDeclaration xmlns="http://webstds.ipc.org/175x/2.0" version="2.0">
   <Product comment="1. This is a generic description of the substances as the actual compostion of the substances are either considered proprietary or no official CAS number is available. If a CAS number is given, it is the closest match available." unitType="Each">
      <MaterialInfo>
         <ExemptionList>
            <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
            <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature type solders (i.e., lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)" identity="7(a)"/>
         </ExemptionList>
         <ExemptionList>
            <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
            <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature type solders (i.e., lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)" identity="7(a)"/>
         </ExemptionList>
         <HomogeneousMaterialList>
            <HomogeneousMaterial materialGroupName="Other Non-ferrous Metals and Alloys" name="Solder Paste 1">
               <Amount UOM="mg" value="7.02"/>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="IPC" identity="EUROHS-0508"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Lead/lead compounds">
                     <Substance name="Lead">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7439-92-1"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="6.4935"/>
                        <SubstanceExemption description="Lead in high melting temperature type solders (i.e., lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)" identity="7(a)"/>
                     </Substance>
                     <SubstanceCatExemptionList>
                        <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
                        <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature type solders (i.e., lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)" identity="7(a)"/>
                     </SubstanceCatExemptionList>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="Supplier" identity="Supplier"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Lead alloy">
                     <Substance name="Silver (Ag)">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7440-22-4"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="0.1755"/>
                     </Substance>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="Supplier" identity="Supplier"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Lead alloy">
                     <Substance name="Tin (Sn)">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7440-31-5"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="0.351"/>
                     </Substance>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
            </HomogeneousMaterial>
            <HomogeneousMaterial materialGroupName="Other Non-ferrous Metals and Alloys" name="Post-plating">
               <Amount UOM="mg" value="3.85"/>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="Supplier" identity="Supplier"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Pure metal">
                     <Substance name="Tin (Sn)">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7440-31-5"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="3.85"/>
                     </Substance>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
            </HomogeneousMaterial>
        </HomogeneousMaterialList>      
     </MaterialInfo>
    </Product>
</MainDeclaration>

Expected Output file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MainDeclaration xmlns="http://webstds.ipc.org/175x/2.0" version="2.0">
   <Product comment="1. This is a generic description of the substances as the actual compostion of the substances are either considered proprietary or no official CAS number is available. If a CAS number is given, it is the closest match available." unitType="Each">
      <MaterialInfo>        
         <ExemptionList>
            <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
            <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature type solders (i.e., lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)" identity="7(a)"/>
         </ExemptionList>
         <HomogeneousMaterialList>
            <HomogeneousMaterial materialGroupName="Other Non-ferrous Metals and Alloys" name="Solder Paste 1">
               <Amount UOM="mg" value="7.02"/>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="IPC" identity="EUROHS-0508"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Lead/lead compounds">
                     <Substance name="Lead">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7439-92-1"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="6.4935"/>
                        <SubstanceExemption description="Lead in high melting temperature type solders (i.e., lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)" identity="7(a)"/>
                     </Substance>
                     <SubstanceCatExemptionList>
                        <ExemptionListID authority="IPC" identity="EL2011/534/EU"/>
                        <Exemption description="Lead in high melting temperature type solders (i.e., lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)" identity="7(a)"/>
                     </SubstanceCatExemptionList>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="Supplier" identity="Supplier"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Lead alloy">
                     <Substance name="Silver (Ag)">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7440-22-4"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="0.1755"/>
                     </Substance>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="Supplier" identity="Supplier"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Lead alloy">
                     <Substance name="Tin (Sn)">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7440-31-5"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="0.351"/>
                     </Substance>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
            </HomogeneousMaterial>
            <HomogeneousMaterial materialGroupName="Other Non-ferrous Metals and Alloys" name="Post-plating">
               <Amount UOM="mg" value="3.85"/>
               <SubstanceCategoryList>
                  <SubstanceCategoryListID authority="Supplier" identity="Supplier"/>
                  <SubstanceCategory name="Pure metal">
                     <Substance name="Tin (Sn)">
                        <SubstanceID authority="CAS" identity="7440-31-5"/>
                        <Amount UOM="mg" value="3.85"/>
                     </Substance>
                  </SubstanceCategory>
               </SubstanceCategoryList>
            </HomogeneousMaterial>
        </HomogeneousMaterialList>      
     </MaterialInfo>
    </Product>
</MainDeclaration>
```

Comment: What is the difference to your previous question? What have you tried?

Comment: Please show your best efforts at solving this. In your previous question you said you had tried something and it didn't work. You need to show us what code you have written, what output you are getting, and how this differs from your required output.

Comment: In general, as the more complete XML you have shown uses a namespace `xmlns="http://webstds.ipc.org/175x/2.0"`, any suggestions you have received so far will only work if you declare `xpath-default-namespace="http://webstds.ipc.org/175x/2.0"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` (or `xsl:transform`) root element of the XSLT. But as you have also shown lots of more elements it is not clear whether the elimation of duplicates is only needed for some (which ones exactly?) of them or for all elements having a certain identity.

Comment: Need to remove the duplicate element for only <ExemptionList> based on the <Exemption> tag  attribute value(@identity)  .
Rest of the file remains the same.

Comment: Below is the XSLT template used by me,
<xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='MainDeclaration']/*[local-name()='Product']/*[local-name()='MaterialInfo']"> <xsl:copy><xsl:for-each-group select="/*[local-name()='MainDeclaration']/*[local-name()='Product']/*[local-name()='MaterialInfo']/*[local-name()='ExemptionList']" group-by="/*[local-name()='MainDeclaration']/*[local-name()='Product']/*[local-name()='MaterialInfo']/*[local-name()='ExemptionList']/*[local-name()='Exemption']/@identity"><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:copy></xsl:template>

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 you could do it as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://webstds.ipc.org/175x/2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[ExemptionList]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" composite="yes" group-by="boolean(self::ExemptionList), Exemption/@identity">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="head(current-grouping-key())">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3 is supported with Saxon 9.8 or later or AltovaXML 2017 R3 and later.